Pros and cons of reusing a DependencyProperty vs. creating a new one
I'm in the process of creating my own custom control. The main control inside my custom control will be a TextBox, and of course my custom control should have a DependencyProperty for text, that is inside this TextBox.
Now I could reuse the TextProperty of the TextBox class (using the AddOwner function of said TextProperty) or I could create my own new TextProperty (using the static DependencyProperty.Register).
But I couldn't find any hint to decide for one way over the other? The amount of code to write is nearly the same, so why should I pick reusing over creating (or vice versa)?

Have you considered a user control? Just bind your textbox text property and maybe build a view model  suits your user control. Difficult to advise meaningfully without a lot more info. Like what you're trying to achieve.  Custom controls are only really a good idea if you intend re templating them in several different ways imo.

For your use case there's little difference between using AddOwner and making a new DP. Given that AddOwner allows you to supply your own PropertyMetadata there's nothing I can think of that you can't accomplish with AddOwner that you could by registering a fresh property. Internally DPs are little more than an integer to serve as an indexor to a property bucket, and metadata that defines callbacks and behavior.

@Andy: Thank you, my question was more a general one regarding when to use AddOwner and when to create a new DP, because I didn't find any information about that, all websites I found only explain that there is an "AddOwner" and how to use it, but not when to use it.

@EmperorEto: Thank you. Do you by any chance have an example, when it is better to use "AddOwner" and what the advantages are?

I think you'd "AddOwner" only if you had some architectural or convention-based rationale. You're basically just telling your consumers "this is conceptually the same property as X, just on a different control". Substantively I don't think it adds anything. The WPF docs for AddOwner mention one example being both Border and Control having a BorderBrush property. Maybe it was originally for performance to help keep the DP key count smaller. Honestly I think it reflects a bit of overengineering which is why it's not in most other WPF variant frameworks.
